# Two short pulses generated when input goes high

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-redstone

I made a mob grinder that is based on dark room, dispensers with water buckets and a fall damage:

[image: image description]

What I need now is to generate two short pulses when monster hits the tripwire to quickly spawn and remove water and push them down

Comment: How much ##x## area u are using as darkness?

Comment: 16 x 7. It's kinda defined by the maximum water stream length.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a classical piston short pulser and multiply the output. Here's a schematic depiction (top and side view).

[image: Double short pulser]

Place a sticky piston with a block on top (yellow), and place a repeater facing into the block. This is your input (green). Place redstone dust on two sides of the block. Powering the block will cause the piston to extend after 1 tick, but before that, the dust will be powered. Use repeaters to delay one of the signals by at least 2 ticks. Since it's only a one-tick pulse, you have to use multiple 1 tick repeaters, IIRC (2 ticks might work).

The piston will retract when your input signal turns off.

Comment: Just curious where did you get these schematics from?

Comment: @ModDL http://mordritch.com/mc_rss/ It's pretty awkward to use sometimes, especially for multi-layer structures, and severely outdated (no comparators or hoppers), but it works for simple stuff.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a redstone repeater to make a delay between the two redstone signals needed to deploy and withdraw the water.  I recommend a pulse limiter so that the first pulse ends before the second pulse starts.

All that said, it may be more time-efficient to simply hook a clock generator to the dispensers instead.  Indeed, a clock circuit may be more effective;  more mobs can spawn before they get pushed off.

Comment: I created a pulse limiter and repeater schema, but it sometimes breaks - the water remains running and the monsters do not spawn any more.